# Random effects - Determining mixed model with multiple random effects?

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, blocking

I'm currently trying to find the best way to analyze whether habitat restoration treatments affect arthropod family richness on a sand dune ecosystem and am having trouble determining the random effects and fixed effects in my model.

Two treatments (herbicide and mechanical removal) and a control were conducted on 9 randomized blocks within a preserve. Each block contains three plots (ex., 1H, 1S, 1C -> Block 1; 2H, 2S, 2C -> Block 2). And each block/plot was sampled twice in two different sessions (sess), Spring or Summer. Because of this, there are a total of 54 data points where I received different numbers for my Families response variable.

Spring session x 9 blocks x 3 plots each = 27 plots,
Summer session x 9 blocks x 3 plots each = 27 plots

Other factors that could be affecting arthropod composition could be abiotic factors like side (Side) of the sand dune preserve (East side - at the top of the ridge with larger sand particles or West side - lower elevation and similar to ground level with smaller sand particles). Also aspect (Aspect) in reference to sun direction. Some of the plots are facing N, others facing S, E, or W.

With my understanding, the response variable would be family richness (Families), the independent variable would be treatment (Treat), and random/confounding factors would be Block, Plot, Side, and Aspect since those were not controlled?

I think Plot could be nested in Block, but I'm not too sure. I may take out aspect and side depending on if 3-4 random effects can even be  analyzed.

Fixed : Treatment
Random: Block, Plot, Aspect, Side

I tried to do a linear model using lmer and following that with a post-hoc test, but I'm not too sure if this is the right result because of my statistical interpretation of the fixed and random effects.

I am planning to analyze my data in R.

Any help on whether I'm understanding my variables correctly/incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I can't quite tell from your question how the treatments were allocated to blocks and plots. You have 3 treatments including control. Was a different treatment applied to each of the 3 plots within a block? Or were there 3 separate blocks for each of the 3 treatments, with all plots within a block receiving the same treatment? Also, what is your measure of "arthropod family richness "? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.